# A joint density function with issues in the conditional density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying some joint density function problems and trying to get a conditional probability function I don't know if I did wrong something or the problem is missing something. It says that let 
$$\; f_{XY}(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
cx,  & 0<x<y<4 \\
0, & \text{a.o.c. }
\end{cases}$$
So I got that $c=\frac{3}{32}$ for $f_{XY}$ to be a joint probability density function and then got that:
$$
f_Y(y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{3}{64}y^2, & 0<y<4\\
0, &a.o.c.
\end{cases}
$$
and, since $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$, I got that
$$
f_{X|Y}(x|y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{2x}{y^2},&0<x<y<4\\
0,&a.o.c.
\end{cases}
$$
but
$$
f_{X|Y}(0.6|1)=1.2
$$
Am I doing something wrong or could it be that the statement missed something?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a density being greater than $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Densities can be greater than $1$: they are not probabilities.

In particular the conditional density $f_{X\mid Y=1}^{}(x)=2x$ when $0 \lt x \lt 1$ (and zero otherwise) is the density of a triangular distribution even though it is greater than $1$ when $\frac12 \lt x \lt 1$.

The cumulative distribution function is a probability, and in this example is $F_{X\mid Y=1}(x)=P(X \le x \mid Y=1)={{x}^2}$ when $0 \lt x \lt 1$, which is never greater than $1$.

Comment: I see, think I missed to read that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with a *density function* (in this case a conditional density) being greater than $1$ at some places. Densities are not probabilities.

For example, let $W$ be uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,0.1]$. Then the density function of $W$ is $10$ in this interval.

*Remark:* Your calculations are correct.